# Get Selected Item on Spinner

Tags: android, listview

i am new at android, i have a spinner, a button and a listview.
When i selected item on spinner and clicked the button, the listview will filled with data from database, but i get problem on the way to do that.

Here is my layout code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Select Color" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="CEK" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

And here my activity

```
public class help_activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Spinner spinner1;
SQLiteConnector sqlConnect;
ListView lvUsers;
Button b1;
String colors[] = {"Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black", "Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_help);

    lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    sqlConnect = new SQLiteConnector(this);
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
     final Spinner selectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(spinner1
             .getSelectedItemPosition());

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sqlConnect.getAllRecord());

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            **if (selectSpinner == spinner1.getItemAtPosition(2)) {
                lvUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
            }**
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });





}
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,colors );
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
      }
```

please tell me where I did wrong and how to fix them, thanks

Edited: the bold point on activity is the problem

Comment: spinners have an onItemSelectedListener implementation

Comment: `spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()` spinner1 is not defined at this point. `findViewById(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition())` what do you expect that to do? why don't you use `findViewById(R.id.spinner1)` like for the other views?

Comment: to njzk2: if i get wrong on that, please tell me how to retrieve data from database based on selected item on spinner, i mean when i selected color blue the data will showed on listview but when i choose other color the data wont showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerID);
```

While in `onclick` If you want to retrive Selected Item do following.

```
String textOfSpinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: sory, i has tried with all my knowledge, but i still didt know what should i do with that string, please can you explain more ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.You can use this string to do anything you want on button click for example if you have a form and you want to submit it on button click then you need to retrive selected item of spinner.

Comment: i mean, how should i fill the if statement using that string ?
i was trying many way, but non of them working

Comment: `if(textOfSpinner.equals("checkForYours"))`

Comment: thanks a lot TAsk, very very helpfull for newbie

Answer (score 1):

your listview won't get refreshed and show new content until you call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ()
```

Call this after you have retrieved the data you wish to provide in your list view

Comment: thanks for your helpfull information, i will use it